# Hexo : How to read query param of the URL in ejs by using hexo framework helpers?

Tags: node.js, ejs, hexo

- **<%- config.url %>** will return domain name.
- **<%- url_for(page.path) %>** will return remaining URL after domain name but not the query param?

Can anyone help me to  read query param ?

For example : http://localhost:4000/create.html?step=1

- **<%- config.url %>** --> http://localhost:4000
- **<%- url_for(page.path) %>** --> create.html
- **<%- what is the helper to read this %>** --> step=1

Answer (score 1):

Hexo helpers will be executed at build time, so there is no way they can be aware of the query parameter on the client side.

For your need, you'll have to use JavaScript on the client side: `window.location.search` will give you `?step=1`.